# Getting Type Error when include Djoser urls together with Swagger

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger, django-swagger

I have django-swagger working properly with my API. However, when i try including Djoser urls to my urlpatterns, I get the following traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /docs/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bo/env/home365/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/bo/env/home365/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/bo/env/home365/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 52, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/bo/env/home365/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/bo/env/home365/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/bo/env/home365/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 483, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/bo/env/home365/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 443, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/bo/env/home365/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/bo/env/home365/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework_swagger/views.py", line 32, in get
    schema = generator.get_schema(request=request)
  File "/Users/bo/env/home365/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/schemas/generators.py", line 286, in get_schema
    links = self.get_links(None if public else request)
  File "/Users/bo/env/home365/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/schemas/generators.py", line 324, in get_links
    link = view.schema.get_link(path, method, base_url=self.url)
  File "/Users/bo/env/home365/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/schemas/inspectors.py", line 195, in get_link
    fields += self.get_serializer_fields(path, method)
  File "/Users/bo/env/home365/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/schemas/inspectors.py", line 337, in get_serializer_fields
    for field in serializer.fields.values():
  File "/Users/bo/env/home365/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 363, in fields
    for key, value in self.get_fields().items():
  File "/Users/bo/env/home365/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 1026, in get_fields
    field_names, declared_fields, extra_kwargs
  File "/Users/bo/env/home365/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 1373, in get_uniqueness_extra_kwargs
    field_names, declared_fields, extra_kwargs
  File "/Users/bo/env/home365/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 1455, in _get_model_fields
    if '.' in source or source == '*':
TypeError: argument of type 'CharField' is not iterable
```

Here is my urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import include, path, re_path

from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view

from apps.core import api as core_api

schema_view = get_swagger_view(title='365home API')

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'core/fabric', core_api.FabricViewSet,
    base_name='FabricViewSet')

urlpatterns = [
    path('docs/', schema_view),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('v1/api/', include(router.urls)),
    path('djoser/', include('djoser.urls')),

    path('', include('apps.frontend.urls')),
]
```

If I include djoser.urls.jwt or djoser.urls.authotoken – there are no problems. If I include djoser.urls.base – problem occurs.

Can't find a lot on this issue.

I am using django 2.0.1, DRF 3.8.2, django-rest-swagger 2.1.2 and djoser 1.1.5.

Did anyone face this problem?

Comment: Can you check if the problem still occurs in latest `djoser` version? There were some fixes lately. If it still occurs, I'd like to know a little bit more: does this happen when you run `runserver` or go to specific url, etc. Note that there is no reference to `djoser` in the stack trace.

Comment: I actually had a problem in my serializers. Everything worked fine when I've fixed that